# Can I implement Android License Verification Library post App Published for next versions?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have already published Paid Android App and many users have bought it. Unfortunately, I came across Android License Verification Library (LVL) now. So, is it possible to implement it in next versions of my app (as an update) to provide license checking?

I don't want that all the existing users face License Errors/Issues after updating my app(implemented with Android LVL).

Has anybody tried it? Is it working successfully for existing app users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did that and there was no problem: users who didn't update to the version with LVL are still able to run their versions as there is no LVL to prevent this.

Users who updated and new users have an LVL version which permits access.